# The task manager is completely crazy. The math doesnt even add up to the complete CPU or CPU usage

Tags: cpu-usage, task-manager, windows-11

As you can see, the math doesn't even add up to the actual usage

[image: Screenshot of Task Manager]

This has been happening ever since I have been using my monitor on my laptop. Please do help.

Comment: What is your question? Is something not working? Are you just asking for an explanation of what you are seeing?

Comment: Your forgetting about the services that are running in the background. Task Manager is accurate but you are right it doesn’t do a good job at providing the complete breakdown of your system usage.  Process Explorer and RAMMap do a better job of that

Answer (score 0):

Your question refers to the CPU-usage while your referenced image shows sorting by GPU-usage.

Assuming you indeed meant CPU-usage:

Look out for the System Interrupts as well. Also the task-manager shows the CPU-Load absolute not relative to the actual CPU-Frequency (and -Threading/-HyperThreading if applicable to your CPU). When you switch to the Performance-tab you will see that depending on your actual Frequency the percentage reflects the used potential not the amount of processing-power relative to the actual frequency. For example: If you limit your 3.2GHz CPU to max 50% it will be limited to 1.6GHz and the percentage reflects that cap-limit not the Utilization relative to the available 1.6GHz.

Yes, it is annoying.

If you actually meant the GPU-usage, you are in a similar situation, where you have to differ by calls made via GDI/DirectX/OpenGL/Vulkan (which are measured) versus Hardware-Overlays, which are not represented in the overall-load shown, but are added in the application-specific load.

Also the GPU-load is reported by the GPU, which is driver/vendor-dependent - if you need exact numbers you might want to find the specific monitoring-software for your graphics-card.

Yes, it is annoying.

Regarding GPU, if you use Hyper-V/RemoteFX/gWSL - depending on the family, version and edition of your Windows OS - different techniques are used to either passthrough or partition the GPU-capabilities and performance. This affects the sum-up in task-manager as well.

In short: The task-manager is (sadly) not a reliable hardware-monitoring-tool as it relies on the reporting of the subsystems.

The only data shown in TaskManager that is actually safe to use/interpret is:

Speed, Processes, Threads, Handles, Uptime in standard-view or core-specific split-view, as well as the optional kernel-times visualization.

Yes, it is annoying.

Comment: I meant both the CPU and GPU, both. Their math never adds up, the laptop frequently hangs up, and its always at 80% CPU and 50% GPU, around that. As I said, this has only happened ever since I used it on a monitor. Do you have a solution/fix for this please?

Comment: Okay, you should have mentioned that you are asking for a hint regarding handling a hardware shutdown/freeze. In almost all cases this happens due to either timeout-limits reached for tasks in the queue (Watchdog-BSOD) and/or due to temperature sensors reaching the critical mark. The latter is due to the way heatsinks/piping/venting is designed and the simple fact that literally no manufacturer uses actual copper-conductors and thermal-grease, but uses ready-made pads which do not do the job. I circumvent the problem by limiting the cpu-/gpu-frequency in the actual powerplan active in Windows.

Comment: Regarding "always at 80% CPU and 50% GPU": Check the frequency shown when it is at these marks. Because 80% is absolute to the maximum possible INCLUDING Turbo/Boost. So if your CPU runs at a nominal maximum of 2.67GHz (for example a 2nd Gen. Core i7 M), then that would be equivalent to 100% of the CPU-frequency in the specifications, but due to the fact it has a Boost up to 3.17GHz, which by Windows is considered the theoretically possible 100% shown in taskmanager, it shows 80% when Boost is disabled. This in turn indicates your cpu-microcode/firmware is outdated or a wrong driver installed.